# how to connect to online database in godaddy cpanel using vb.net

Tags: mysql, .net, database, vb.net, visual-studio

I can't connect to my online database, I'm using the cPanel of GoDaddy. I tried to add a host in remote MySQL, like '192.68.0.%' but same error gets thrown. The connection string that I used in this is the same connection string that I used on my website.

My code:

```
Try
    Dim MySQLConnection = New MySqlConnection
    MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = "server=www.***.com; port=3306; user=username; password=password; database=database;"
    MySQLConnection.Open()
    MsgBox("Success!")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

I also tried this:

```
Try
    Dim MySQLConnection = New MySqlConnection
    MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = "localhost; port=3306; user=username; password=password; database=database;"
    MySQLConnection.Open()
    MsgBox("Success!")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

I get this error with both codes:

> Authentication to host '148.72.232.107' for user 'username' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'username'@'49.148.94.47' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this by:

1. Go to your cPanel account.
2. Under Databases, click Remote MySQL.
3. Add Access Host, according to your IP error.

In my error I add '49.148.94.47'. 
I can now connect to my online database using MySQL, GoDaddy - cPanel.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim cnQ As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server_IP;Initial Catalog=DataBase_Name;User ID=you_User_Name;Password=your_Password;")
```

Comment: Why does this code fixes the OP's issue? Please add a description on why your answer works and what it does. Code-only answers are frowned-upon and can be deleted on reviews. This is a suggestion for this and future answers. Thanks!